# Line and Points using asp.net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, charts

I have data in data table like below.
[image]

I am trying to make graph like below using asp.net chart control (made graph in excel with some test data)

[image]

points are X and Y values.  lines are linear, exponential,  logarithmic and power values.

So how can I make this chart in asp.net (vb.net or c#)? I am newbie to chart control.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article/guide on the MSDN site describes it pretty well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx).  There are also a number of links from that page that go into additional detail. (Currently doing chart controls myself, and MSDN really helped.)